# Adicionar Subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte query para obter NotaPT `(category = 3)` como posso na mesma query obter a NotaMT `(category = 11)` Estou tentando assim, mas recebo o mesmo valor para NotaPT e NotaMT, abaixo código e imagem de saída:

```
select u.firstname as Aluno, u.lastname as escola, userid, u.department as turma, q.category as cat,


(select avg(fraction)*10 where cat = 3) as NotaPT,

(select avg(fraction)*10 where cat = 11) as NotaMT


FROM mdl_question_attempt_steps qas

inner join mdl_user u on u.id=qas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.id=qas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question q On q.id=qa.questionid

group by userid, turma
order by turma asc, NotaPT DESC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não bastaria agrupar também por categoria e selecionar as que pretende calcular?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss como eu poderia fazer isso, bastaria adicionar a coluna `category` em GROUP BY? e como obteria separadamente as notas de Português e Matemática de cada Aluno? 

Já consigo pegar as notas de Português (3) mas não sei como chamar Matemática (11), usando as mesmas informações de Português mudando apenas a categoria. já quebrei a cabeça mas não consegui

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss deu certo ao agrupar por categoria também, Obrigado!